# How to assign a specific namespace only to a specific nodepool in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We are using AKS v1.19.11 version and due to some application speicfic requirements, We need to have a specific namespace to be assigned to a speicifc nodepol. for example, if our main app is holding in the namespace "main", all the related components of this namespace should be using noodpool called "main". Not looking for a solution likeNormal nodeslector parameters in pod wise and looking for how ut can be achieved in namespace wise.